# Equivalent definitions of congruences (in context of universal algebra)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, intuition, equivalence-relations, universal-algebra

I am familiar with this (informal) definition of congruence relation (or simply congruence):

(1) *A congruence is an equivalence relation on an algebraic structure that is compatible with the structure in the sense that algebraic operations done with equivalent elements will yield equivalent elements.*

(Particular definition of a congruence then depends on the type of algebraic structure under consideration).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation) says that

An equivalent formulation in the universal algebra context is the following:

(2) *A congruence relation on an algebra A is a subset of the direct product A × A that is both an equivalence relation on A and a subalgebra of A × A.*

**My question:** Is the definition (2) valid for any algebraic structure? And intuitively, why are these two definitions ((1),(2)) compatible?

I mean, it is clear to me that any congruence relation is an equivalence relation. But the second criterium is just being a subalgebra of the direct product, and here I feel like I don´t see why it is enough to see that we have a congruence. How does being a subalgebra of A x A "contribute" to being compatible with the algebraic structure?

I hope my question is clear, thank you for providing any intuition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, (2) is valid for all universal algebraic structures.

A relation $R\subseteq A\times B$ being a subalgebra expresses exactly that $R$ is compatible with the operations of $A$ and $B$:

$$(a_i,b_i)\in R\implies \underset i{\large\mu\,}(a_i,b_i)=(\underset i{\large\mu\,}a_i,\ \underset i{\large\mu\,} b_i)\in R$$
for any basic operation $\mu$.